# Can batch size cause incorrect predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, stateful

If i have over 100,000 samples, I'm wondering if learning is wrong when using a single batch size model, so i can make inaccurate predictions. And I wonder if the size of the batchs simply affects learning speed, or anything else.

Comment: Batch size might effect the learning speed in some cases but I have not come across any case where there are wrong predictions due to batch size, given you are training your model for good number of epochs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO**.

The batch size on average only influences the speed of your learning, not the quality of learning.

For the explanation, please go through this [Link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/does-batch-size-in-keras-have-any-effects-in-results-quality)

Answer (score -1):

In general larger batch sizes will make the error decrease in the direction of the negative gradient of the cost function. 
Having smaller batches is sometimes advantageous, because it can make your training alot faster. A smaller batch sizes will train quicker, but may decrease the error in a suboptimal direction. It is basically a trade off between stepping speed and stepping direction.